# Replace symlinks by target file content

Tags: git, svn, version-control, symlink, version-control-migration

I've got an svn tree which I'd like to turn into multiple independent git repositories. One aspect of this migration is that inodes which are cross-module symlinks in the subversion tree should be replaced by actual file content in the git repositories. So if, at some point, `A/foo` is a symlink to `B/foo`, then the corresponding git commit should have a normal file `A/foo` whose content is the content of `B/foo`. If some later svn commit changes the content of `B/foo`, then the git module for `A` should have a matching commit to reflect this change.

**What tools can I use for this?**

Right now, here is the best plan I could come up with so far:

1. [Clone the whole svn into git](http://git-scm.com/book/ch8-2.html#Subversion)
2. [`fast-export`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-export) that
3. Massage the output using some custom-written throw-away code to turn symlinks into content files
4. [`fast-import`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import) the result into a new single git repo
5. [Create submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359424/1468366) from that

But perhaps you can suggest easier solutions, using existing code, existing functionality, existing tools, or making use of shortcuts I haven't thought of.

Perhaps there is even a way to handle more of these steps on the subversion side. Since I made heavy use of creating subversion copies of files, and since that concept can afaik be expressed only poorly in git concepts, I fear that the above approach might loose version history due to copied files.